# keyup, keypress event not fire in extjs grd column

Tags: extjs, extjs3

This my Grid column

```
MyColumn3Ui = Ext.extend(Ext.grid.NumberColumn, {
    constructor: function(cfg) {
        cfg = cfg || {};
        MyColumn3Ui.superclass.constructor.call(this, Ext.apply({
            dataIndex: 'ID',
            header: 'name',
            sortable: true,
            width: 75,
            align: 'right',
            id: 'name_col',
            editor: {
                xtype: 'numberfield',
                name: 'ID',
                decimalPrecision: 0,
                allowDecimals: false,
                enableKeyEvents: true,
                allowBlank: false,
                maxLength: 5,
                id: 'col_id'
            }
        }, cfg));
    }
});
```

This what i try to fire keyup and keypress event

```
 this.col = Ext.getCmp('col_id');
 this.col.blur = blurFun .createDelegate(this, [this.col, 4,""]);
 this.col.keyup = keyupFun.createDelegate(this, [this.col, 4,""]);
 this.col.keypress = keypressFun .createDelegate(this, [this.col, 4,""]);

 blurFun = function(txtField, length, nextField ) {
    alert('blur');
 }
 keyupFun= function(txtField, length, nextField ) {
    alert('keyup ');
 }
 keypressFun = function(txtField, length, nextField ) {
    alert('keypress');
 }
```

when i click on name column only show `blur` alert. others event not fire in my editable ExtJs grid. what i want to for fire keyup, keypress event in my grid column

Comment: you have to add "enableKeyEvents:true" config to your textfield for bind key events.

Comment: thanks for your help i check with enableKeyEvents: true as my new change code it's not worked for me

Answer (score 0):

To add event listeners to a component, use the [on](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.form.TextField-method-on) function:

```
this.col.on({
    'blur': function(field) {
        alert('blur');
    },
    scope: this
});
```

Comment: i can get `blur` alert using my code but other key event not work for me

Comment: Because you have **overridden** the blur function of the textfield with your code. If you want to use event listeners (and you should!), use the code I suggested. You can use the same syntax for all of the events you mentioned, just change the event name.

Answer (score 0):

col model don't have event like keyup. keyup event fire in the editor

```
this.col.keyup = keyupFun.createDelegate(this, [this.col, 4,""]);
```

change to

```
 this.col.editor.keyup = keyupFun.createDelegate(this, [this.col.editor, 4,""]);
```